# How to calculate the size of an aggregation when limit of 16 mb is crossed

Tags: database, mongodb, express, aggregation

I want to calculate the size of a few interrelated documents in MongoDB for a particular application User.
I am performing aggregation and in the end doing projection on the bsonSize, but when the document size exceeds the **limit of 16 MB**, this approach is not working.

I think there must be some better way to solve this problem, I request to the experienced developer who is viewing this question to share a better approach.

This is what my aggregation array looks like,

```
[
      {
        $match: {
          user: userId
        }
      }, {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'anyvalidcollection1',
          localField: 'validlocalfield1',
          foreignField: 'validforeignfield1',
          as: 'alias1'
        }
      }, $lookup: {
          from: 'anyvalidcollection2',
          localField: 'validlocalfield2',
          foreignField: 'validforeignfield2',
          as: 'alias2'
        },
       $lookup: {
          from: 'anyvalidcollection3',
          localField: 'validlocalfield3',
          foreignField: 'validforeignfield3',
          as: 'alias3'
        },
       $lookup: {
          from: 'anyvalidcollection4',
          localField: 'validlocalfield4',
          foreignField: 'validforeignfield4',
          as: 'alias4'
        },
        $lookup: {
          from: 'anyvalidcollection5',
          localField: 'validlocalfield5',
          foreignField: 'validforeignfield5',
          as: 'alias5'
        }
      }, {
        $project: {
          size: {
            $bsonSize: '$$ROOT'
          },
          fileSize: '$file_data.size'
        }
      }, {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$fileSize',
          includeArrayIndex: '0',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          _id: 'sum',
          totalSize: {
            $sum: '$size'
          },
          totalFileSize: {
            $sum: '$fileSize'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: An aggregation pipeline with 5 `$lookup` is typically a poor design of your data. NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not like relational SQL database, they are not optimized for joins (some products do not even support joins at all) and excessive use of it should be avoided. Using `$unwind` and immediately afterwards `$group` looks also poor. You can run `$sum` operator also directly on arrays.

Comment: Looks like you use only fields `size` and `fileSize`. `$unset` all fields which are not required as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If document in the pipeline is `> 16MB` `$bsonSize` will complain of document size, even if returned documents are < 16MB.

But a simple way to solve this is to do many bson sizes, for example if you have many fields with lots of data, `field1,field2,field3`

You can do something like the bellow

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"size": 
     {"$add": 
       [{"$bsonSize": {"field1": "$field1"}},
        {"$bsonSize": {"field2": "$field2"}},
        {"$bsonSize": {"field3": "$field3"}}]}}}])
```

You also have 5 lookups that looks alot, maybe you can reduce them, if you change your schema.